# Why did the pilot in this EC135 crash change the throttle setting after encountering wake turbulence?

Tags: helicopter, accidents, throttle, wake-turbulence, fadec

I’m confused in [this accident](https://app.ntsb.gov/pdfgenerator/ReportGeneratorFile.ashx?EventID=20001211X11617&AKey=1&RType=Final&IType=FA) why the Eurocopter EC135 pilot decided to manipulate the throttle after encountering wake turbulence - I can’t think of a reason for this. Could someone please explain why a pilot would do that?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone except the pilot themselves can talk about their motivation, but hopefully someone can talk to the procedures for dealing with wake turbulence in this type or similar.

Comment: It's possible that the pilot didn't decide to disable autothrottle, it could have been inadvertent.

Answer (score 6):

It's the second sentence on the first page of the report:

> He inadvertently rolled the throttles to manual, and never restabilized the
> engines or main rotor rpm.

Supplemented by (the next sentence):

> In addition, he did not understand the reset procedures for the
> engine controls (FADEC), and never returned the engines to FADEC control.